# Selecting information from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue.

In table I have for example

```
591|15-MA TEST
```

I want to retrieve `15-MA TEST`.

I tried to mix `substring`, `charindex`, `left` - with no use.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Need little more explanation. Better to post some code you tried, it also helps us understand better. Give some example table or string variable, with expected result.

Comment: Did you try replace()?

Comment: What do you mean by *normal sql* - is SQL Server **abnormal** ?!?!?!?!?

Comment: is the string always delimited by `|`? will there always only be one `|`?

Comment: `I tried to mix substring, charindex, left - with no use` adding that may help you.so that you may not get downvotes

Comment: To answer your question, "Yes, someone can help you!"  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to get the starting position.  You do that by using CHARINDEX and then adding 1.  Then you can use SUBSTRING.

(This is assuming the string will always have a single "|" that is the delimiter.)

```
DECLARE @s varchar(50) SET @s = '591|15-MA TEST'

SELECT CHARINDEX('|', @S) AS Position,  
    SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('|', @S) + 1, len(@s)) AS SelectionText
```

**RESULTS**

```
4     15-MA TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @char varchar(100)
select @char = '591|15-MA TEST' 
select SUBSTRING(@char, CHARINDEX('|',@char,1)+1 , LEN(@char))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring('591|15-MA TEST', CHARINDEX( '|', '591|15-MA TEST')+1, LEN('591|15-MA TEST'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get whatever is after the '|' char, then you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    RIGHT([Column Name],LEN([Column Name]) - CHARINDEX('|', [Column Name]))
FROM
    [Table Name]
```